# (lldb) error while retrieving datas from parse in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6, nsdictionary

I am using below function to retrieve datas from parse in swift. But I am getting error in the line "results.objectAtIndex(i) as NSDictionary". I don't know what error and why that error is coming? Kindly read my code and guide me!

```
  func parse_db() {
        var sto_tit = [String] ()
        var results : NSArray = NSArray()
        var par_object : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
        var par_query = PFQuery(className: "story")
        par_query.whereKeyExists("story_title")
        par_query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(NSArray objects, NSError error) in

           if (error != nil) {
               NSLog("error " + error.localizedDescription)
           } else {                   
               results = NSArray(array: objects)

               for i in 0...results.count {
                   println(i) //This line working

                   par_object = results.objectAtIndex(i) as NSDictionary //Error
                   sto_tit = par_object.objectForKey("story_title") as Array

               }
               NSLog("results %@", sto_tit)
           }
      })
    }
```

Error is below:
    0
    (lldb)

```
{
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x10adfc620:  pushq  %rbp
0x10adfc621:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x10adfc624:  pushq  %rbx
0x10adfc625:  pushq  %rax
0x10adfc626:  movq   %rsi, %rcx
0x10adfc629:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x10adfc62c:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x10adfc62e:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x10adfc631:  je     0x10adfc64c               ;swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional 
+ 44
0x10adfc633:  movq   0x82756(%rip), %rsi       ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x10adfc63a:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x10adfc63d:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
0x10adfc640:  callq  0x10adff1ca               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x10adfc645:  testb  %al, %al
0x10adfc647:  movq   %rbx, %rax
0x10adfc64a:  je     0x10adfc653               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 51
0x10adfc64c:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
0x10adfc650:  popq   %rbx
0x10adfc651:  popq   %rbp
0x10adfc652:  retq   
0x10adfc653:  leaq   0xcdc8(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x10adfc65a:  movq   %rax, 0x8ae57(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x10adfc661:  int3   
0x10adfc662:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:
```

returns an NSArray of PFObjects. So when you try

```
var par_object = results.objectAtIndex(i) as NSDictionary
```

will fail, because the ith object of results is a PFObject, which is not convertible to NSDictionary this way.

But you can use

```
par_object = results.objectAtIndex(i) as PFObject
sto_tit = par_object["story_title"] as [String] //Are you sure about that the "story_title" column is an array?
```

And your declaration is wrong use

```
var par_object = PFObject(className: "YOUR_CLASS_NAME")
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have tried, but I am getting this warning, " variable 'par_object' inferred to have type 'AnyObject', which may be unexpected"

Comment: Same error I am receiving, in that same line, after cast par_object to PFObject

Comment: I updated again my answer to cast the column to an array of Strings.

Comment: And when you declare var par_object : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(), that is wrong, it should be a PFObject

Comment: Having 1 doubt? To print "sto_tit" datas, I used this line. "println("Check_1 \(self.sto_tit)")". But, if I use this line inside  FOR-LOOP means, I am getting datas. Otherwise, If I use outside FOR-LOOP, or after ELSE Block I unable to get datas. Same time, this line also not get executed. How to solve this?

Comment: If you use println("Check_1 \(self.sto_tit)") after the for loop, you should see the last element that was set to sto_tit. If you want to see all values that you've setted to sto_tit, you shold add them to an array in the for loop instead of sto_tit, and print it out after.

Comment: func {    
     if()  {}   
     else {
      for i in 0...self.results.count
        {
    
        self.par_object = self.results.objectAtIndex(i) as PFObject
        var sto = self.par_object["story_title"] as String
        self.sto_tit.append(sto)    
        println("Check_1 \(self.sto_tit)") //WORKING
        } //FOR ENDS
        println("Check_2 \(self.sto_tit)") //LINE SKIPPED
     } // ELSE BLOCK ENDS
     println("Check_3 \(self.sto_tit)") // "[]" SIMPLY PRINTING LIKE       THIS
}

Comment: I'm not sure about why both check 2 and 3 is skipped

Comment: Ok Daniel! I have asked this query here. Any time, reply there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861216/unable-to-get-array-value-in-swift