# Unable to get Array Value in SWIFT

Tags: if-statement, swift, nsarray

I retrieved values from parse and stored one by one in an array called "sto_tit". 
But if I try to print the values, I unable to print. It is get printed inside loop only, but not get printed Outside FOR LOOP or OUTSIDE ELSE block,  I don't know what error in my code. Kindly guide me!

MY CODE BELOW:

```
func parse_db()
{

    var sto_tit = [String]() // EITHER GLOBAL DECLARATION or INSIDE BLOCK, SAME ISSUE
    // FACING

    par_query.selectKeys(["story_title"])
    par_query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(NSArray objects, NSError error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("error " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else
        {

            self.results = NSArray(array: objects)
            //NSLog("results %@", results)

            for i in 0...self.results.count
            {


                self.par_object = self.results.objectAtIndex(i) as PFObject
                var sto = self.par_object["story_title"] as String
                sto_tit.append(sto)
                println("Check_1 \(sto_tit)") // PRINTING [A],[AB],[ABC] ...

            } //FOR ENDS
            println("HELLO") // GETS SKIPPED
            println("Check_2 \(sto_tit)") // GETS SKIPPED

        } // ELSE ENDS
        println("Check_3 \(sto_tit)") // GETS SKIPPED

    }) //PARSE ENDS

    println("Check_4 \(sto_tit)") //PRINTING "Check_4 []"

} // BLOCK ENDS
```

Comment: If I understand this question correctly, you seem to be saying "check2" does not get printed.  That means that the entire code in your else block is not getting executed.  What's the code when the if statement is true?

Comment: Ooops! As per my condition, Else block only get execute. So, FOR LOOP will get execute. So, "CHECK_1" will print. But, once FOR LOOP ends,  
CHECK_2 should be execute, but that line gets skipped. Don't know why?

Comment: How is sto_tit declared?

Comment: Hi! I have updated my full code in my question. Guide me.

Comment: I'm looking at you re-post now, but I also tried making sto_tit an instance variable (outside any function, but in the class).  I got the same expected results using your self. syntax.

Comment: Ok! what issue behind my code? How can solve this??

Comment: I hate unresolved issues, and I'm beating my head against the wall on this along with you. I could question a few details, but the central question for me is why Check_2 is not being printed.  Just to try something, try for i in 0..<self.results.count.

Comment: Regardless of what we track this down to I really think you should be using i < self.results.count rather than i = self.results.count in your for loop.

Comment: Maybe nothing is wrong with your code.  Maybe the reason Check_2 is not being printed is in my edit to my answer.  Maybe the for loop is an infinite loop and never gets to the Check_2 print.

Comment: BTW I've backed off on my development of apps with Swift.  For my applications Swift is just too slow (by several orders of magnitude) and I run into these kinds of problems too frequently.  I don't think Swift is quite ready for prime time just yet.

Comment: Thank Lot for u! Now i got. I don't know how to break Infinite loop.  But, I will use standard FOR-LOOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer because it has some code.  I hope this helps you, but if not please let me know.

I pasted the following code into one of my Swift Apps:

```
var sto_tit:[String] = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"];
if(false)
{

}else{

    for var i:Int  = 0; i < 3; i++
    {
        var sto = "story_title"
        sto_tit.append(sto)
        println("Check_1 \(sto_tit)")
    }

    println("Check_2 \(sto_tit)")
}
println("Check_3 \(sto_tit)")
```

The printed result was as expected:

Check_1 [Yes, No, Maybe, story_title]

Check_1 [Yes, No, Maybe, story_title, story_title]

Check_1 [Yes, No, Maybe, story_title, story_title, story_title]

Check_2 [Yes, No, Maybe, story_title, story_title, story_title]

Check_3 [Yes, No, Maybe, story_title, story_title, story_title]

Note that there are some details of my code that are different from yours, but it's the closest I could come quickly.

Also note that check_2 does not get skipped.  I think there's something in your code that is not being posted exactly as it is.

EDIT:

Here's an interesting anomalie,  This code behaves as expected:

```
var sto_tit:[String] = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"];

println("sto_tit count = \(sto_tit.count)")

var j :Int = sto_tit.count

for var i:Int = 0; i < j; i++
{
    var sto = "story_title"
    sto_tit.append(sto)
    println("Check_1 \(sto_tit)")
}
```

but this code sends the for loop into an infinite loop:

```
var sto_tit:[String] = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"];

println("sto_tit count = \(sto_tit.count)")

for var i:Int = 0; i < sto_tit.count; i++
{
    var sto = "story_title"
    sto_tit.append(sto)
    println("Check_1 \(sto_tit)")
}
```

What's up with this?